# Keep attachment after redirect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So, i have a project where i check pdf files the user uploads and i generate warnings.

In case we have Warnings the user will be redirected to the page where he has to upload the file. I display to him the warnings that showed up and i give him the option to proceed with his upload, ignoring the warnings, if he wants to do so.

At the momment the user has to reupload the same file and tick a `checkbox` confirming that he wants to proceed even tho there are warnings.

What i want to do is: Save the uploaded file so that the user doen't have to re upload the pdf.

I thought using something like a `FileInfo` object, but i dont know to use it in the `[HttpGet]` part.

part of the code from the `[HttpPost]` where i generate the warnings and try to save the file.

```
 if (pdfvalidationresult.Warnings.Any())
            {

                TempData["FileName"] = file.FileName;

                file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var filePath = Path.ChangeExtension(
                Path.Combine(Settings.Default.FilesDirectory,
                Path.Combine("temp"), orderId.ToString()), ".pdf");

                FileInfo temporaryFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

                TempData["Existance"] = temporaryFile;

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);



                TempData["warnings"] = pdfvalidationresult.Warnings;
                if (ignoreWarnings == null || ignoreWarnings != true)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "We Have Warnings!");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Session`?

Comment: Just save it to a temporary directory (perhaps give it a `Guid` as a file name) and pass that to the next view and generate a hidden input for it so its posted back, after which you can save it to its permanent location

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, thats what i ll probably try to do. An Guid allready exists so now i am trying to figure a way around this.